# Cannot run nmp i on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to create a react app
I entered command npm i into the console, and it gives this message:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path G:\My Drive\MY PORTFOLIO\react\node_modules\@types
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\MY PORTFOLIO\react\node_modules\@types'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\"user"\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-01T17_08_27_530Z-debug-0.log
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try deleting `G:\My Drive\MY PORTFOLIO\react\node_modules` and try again.

Comment: (As an aside, if `My Drive` is e.g. an OneDrive or Google Drive or other cloud-synced location, it's _not_ a good place to put your project, because `node_modules` will end up being tens of thousands of files.)

Comment: Thank you AKX!!! deleting the folder solved it